# Groundwater cooled heat exchanger - forced air

Tags: plumbing, hvac, water, furnace, cooling

I have kind of a crazy idea I have been scheming - I live in Alaska, and have a private well - the groundwater here is very cold(40-45F) or so. The last couple of summers have been miserable hot up here(A/C is very rare), and I have been looking at cheapy single room or diy air conditioners, and ran across a simple fan with a coiled copper pipe circulating cold water. That got me to thinking, why can't I scale that up, and have a cold water circulating pipe inside my furnace vent. I found some pretty inexpensive Water to air heat exchangers online, with copper pipes, and aluminum fins.

When it gets really hot inside, I turn the furnace fan only on, just to circulate some air. So I figured I could just turn the fan on, and run my sprinklers a bit outside, or do dishes to circulate cold water through the heat exchanger. I wouldn't be looking to cool the air dramatically, just slightly - enough to give some relief on very hot days. Here is a diagram that kind of explains what I am thinking. I also added a loop for the hot water heater, thinking I could switch the heat exchanger over to hot water in the winters.

[image: Heat exhanger scheme]

How crazy is this, and what would the major problems be? I do have a condensate pump already, and I figure the heat exchanger will sweat so I would add a drain there.. Would I be adding so much moisture to the supply air I would also need a de-humidifier? Would the supply air not really cool down at all like I am hoping?

Thank you for any response.

Comment: https://dandelionenergy.com/blog/geothermal-cooling Same idea, but use a **closed loop system** - otherwise you are either raising humidity (not good in the summer) or wasting water or both.

Comment: Yeah, the humidity would be my main concern. I figured I could run a 50 pint dehumidifier in the house as well though. This is a ghetto diy system I'm hoping to build for $200-$250. So drilling geothermal lines is a little out of my price range. As far as wasting water.. This would be using water I am using anywhere in the house.. I wouldn't be just draining the water, and I wouldn't be putting constant strain on my well pump.

Comment: A dehumidifier adds **more** heat. The problem with an open-loop system is that your water usage will probably be nowhere near the amount of cooling you want. But I do see your point - open loop == existing plumbing, closed loop == Add 2x the existing plumbing, plus a pump.

Comment: In thinking about humidity... My air intake is inside my house.. So if warm moist air is passing over the cold heat exchanger, condensing into droplets, draining out the bottom, and being removed by my condensate pump.. Am I not lowering the indoor humiditiy in effect? Im sure i'm way over simplifying that, or completely wrong..

Comment: If it is cold enough, yes. But I'm dubious that a simple setup like you suggest (simple in the sense of "cold water flowing through, not a refrigerant cycle") will get much water to condense out and at the same time you will inevitably end up deciding to run more water through the system in order to increase flow which means more evaporation into the house.

Comment: My cold water pipes in my crawlspace sweat like crazy in the summer, already.. The RH average for last July was 71%, and the avg temp was 70%. So dew point would be like 60F average maybe?

Comment: Could be. And if all that works, it will help. But how much cooling will you get if water only flows when you use it????
Now I'm thinking: What if you didn't have a true closed loop but rather a simple discharge pipe back down into the well - the well could be 100 feet deep but you'd only need to get from the heat exchanger back to the top of the well and it wouldn't be under pressure, so that would make it much simpler. Can't do that with a municipal water system - the question is whether that would be **safe** with a private well.

Comment: yeah i was reading about that.. i would have to dig up 50ft off my yard to lay a new pipe under the frost line back to the well.. interesting though.

Comment: Not necessarily. It would be sloping down anyway (since it's not under pressure). So put in a shutoff inside the house (right where it connects to the heat exchanger). For winter, drain (which should be just "close the shutoff and make sure the pipe drained naturally") and done.

Comment: Or let it pump out into a pond where it eventually goes back to the well in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only cold water to lower a buildings temperature was common many years ago. I have not seen any of the systems that still work but I do know  or was told that they worked. This would be similar to a typical A/C system except that the cooling medium would be water instead of a refrigerant cooling the air.  Know this that most large buildings, schools, hospitals, and office buildings use cooled water to do the A/C since it is easier to circulate a cooled water than to have spot cooling everywhere. In your case, instead of using a refrigerant to cool the water, you will use a dedicated cold water source as your cooling medium. A cold water source is located, a well, an underground stream, or an aquifer that is tapped into and the cold water was pumped into a water coil similar to an A/C coil and the discharge water, now slightly heated is returned back into the source. This idea will work if the source water is cold enough, you can remove and return enough water to suit your needs, and it is allowed by the codes concerning this action. Will your idea work, yes, is it allowed, ?, is it cost effective, I do not know.

Comment: With ground water that cool it probably would work, geothermal heating and cooling has been and is a thing some systems pull water from 1 well and dump it back in another on the other side of the house, the cost of a capped well is the negative here I have seen people use the discharge for watering fields.

Comment: Yeah, my idea is more like energy recovery of the cold groundwater i am already using. I do run sprinklers in the summer, and we use a lot of water in general with laundry, dishes, showers, gardening,etc. The way i will connect it will force cold water through the exchanger before it goes to the water heater so will make use of hot water used as well.  As far as whether it is code, i highly doubt that.  I will install it in a safe manner and It will be easy enough to take out though. Will go along will with the rest of my non code house.

Comment: If you are still looking for more information on using underground water to cool your home do a search on the underground river  or the 4th river in Pittsburgh, Pa.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering the same system but going to rout my cold well water through a 150 gallon tank but use a 3/4 copper coil inside that tank to exchange the coolness to the tank water.

Why? To bank cold water every time there is any water used in the house and the well pump comes on, 48 degree water flows though the copper pipe and if the water in the tank is above 48 degrees there will be an exchange of heat from the tank to the cooper coil in effect heating my well water as it goes though thus cooling the tank water.

Then I will pump the cool tank water through a radiator inline with my HVAC. What do you call that? I don't know how much lower the water will need to be then the 73 degrees my air conditioner is set at but I have no doubt I can achieve some cooling effect.

Will it be enough to completely cool my house and turn off the hvac cooling system and only run the fan? I think so as long as there is cold enough water in the tank. Or, I could use the extra cooling to augment my HVAC resulting in cooler air at the vents and thus the system would run less to achieve the same cooling of the house?

I will be able to run it ether way to see. I can also make the tank larger such as 300 or 500 gallons to bank more cold water. All the tank has to do is hold the water, not hold well water pressure as the well water passing through is contained in the coil. It just passes though and absorbs heat leaving coolness in the tank.

I have a nice plastic IVC 300 gallon tank I got for 25 bucks. No way to get that into the basement but I could bury it behind the house and run well water into and out of it and insulate around it, cheap but good-enough.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/161617)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).